# How do I write a character at codepoint 80 to a file in Windows-1252?

Tags: java, character-encoding, windows-1252

I am trying to write bytes to a file in the windows-1252 charset. The example below, writing the raw bytes of a float to a file, is similar to what I'm doing in my actual program.

In the example given, I am writing the raw hex of 1.0f to test.txt. As the raw hex of 1.0f is *3f 80 00 00* I expect to get **?€(NUL)(NUL)**, as from what I can see in the [Windows 1252 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), *0x3f* should correspond to '**?**', *0x80* should correspond to '**€**', and *0x00* is '**NUL**'. Everything goes fine until I actually try to write to the file; at that point, I get a java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException on the console, and after the program stops on that exception the file only has a single '?' in it. The full console output is below the code down below.

It looks like Java considers the codepoint *0x80* unmappable in the windows-1252 codepage. However, this doesn't seem right – all the codepoints should map to actual characters in that codepage. The problem is definitely with the codepoint *0x80*, as if I try with 0.5f (*3f 00 00 00*) it is happy to write **?(NUL)(NUL)(NUL)** into the file, and does not throw the exception. Experimenting with other codepages doesn't seem to work either; looking at key encodings supported by the Java language [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html), only the UTF series will not give me an exception, but due to their encoding they don't give me codepoint *0x80* in the actual file.

I'm going to try just using bytes instead so I don't have to worry about string encoding, but is anyone able to tell me why my code below gives me the exception it does?

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CharsetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float max = 1.0f;
        System.out.println("Checking " + max);
        String stringFloatFormatHex = String.format("%08x", Float.floatToRawIntBits(max));
        System.out.println(stringFloatFormatHex);
        byte[] bytesForFile = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(stringFloatFormatHex);
        String stringForFile = new String(bytesForFile);
        System.out.println(stringForFile);

        String charset = "windows-1252";
        try {
            Writer output = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("test.txt"), Charset.forName(charset));
            output.write(stringForFile);
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Checking 1.0
3f800000
?�  
Input length = 1
java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:285)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:265)
    at CharsetTest.main(CharsetTest.java:21)
```

Comment: See the [`String(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)) constructor. Not sure what your default charset is, but what is likely to happen is: The second character can not be mapped, so it will be turned into �, the unicode replacement character, which can not be encoded in Windows-1252.

Comment: Using ```System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());```, it looks like my default charset is UTF-8. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: `\0x80` is not a valid utf-8 sequence, therefore it is replaced with �.

Comment: Oh, I see! You're right; the problem is on the instruction ```String stringForFile = new String(bytesForFile);```, below the ```DatatypeConverter```. As I construct a string without providing a charset, it defaults to UTF-8, which doesn't work. However, it only throws an exception when it writes to a file.

Comment: Yeah, because � can't be encoded in windows-1252, so it throws an exception. Happens with all characters that can't be encoded in some charset, which is a good thing. The only question is if it is a good thing that the String constructor silently replaces invalid sequences. But now it's impossible to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit:*** The problem is on the instruction `String stringForFile = new String(bytesForFile);`, below the `DatatypeConverter`. As I was constructing a string without providing a charset, it uses my default charset, which is UTF-8, which doesn't have a symbol for codepoint *80*. However, it only throws an exception when it writes to a file. This doesn't happen in the code below because my refactor (keeping in mind Johannes Kuhn's suggestion in the comments) doesn't use the `String(byte[])` constructor without specifying a charset.

[Johannes Kuhn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn) suggestion about the [`String(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)) constructor gave me some good clues. I've ended up with the following code, which looks like it works fine: even printing the **€** symbol to the console as well as writing it to test.txt. That suggests that codepoint *80* can be translated using the windows-1252 codepage.

If I were to guess at this point why this code works but the other didn't, I'd still be confused, but I would guess it was something around the conversion in `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(stringFloatFormatHex);`. That looks to be the main difference, although I'm not sure why it would matter.

Anyway, the code below works (and I don't even have to turn it into a string; I can write the bytes to a file with `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.txt"); fos.write(bytes); fos.close();`), so I'm happy with this one.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class BytesCharsetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float max = 1.0f;
        System.out.println("Checking " + max);
        int convInt = Float.floatToRawIntBits(max);
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(convInt).array();

        String charset = "windows-1252";
        try {
            String stringForFile = new String(bytes, Charset.forName(charset));
            System.out.println(stringForFile);

            Writer output = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("test.txt"), Charset.forName(charset));
            output.write(stringForFile);
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Checking 1.0
?€  

Process finished with exit code 0
```